# Enum htmlTextWriterStyle modified then stored in another similar container

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, class, enums

I was searching a data source for all common style types available in asp.net 
and `htmlTextWriterStyle` appears to have all I could ask for.

if there's other source I could use I'll be happy to know .

what i was trying to achieve is to copy it's values to any other type of data "container"

that is differ from enum , more flexible though it's value still can be accessed via

```
var test = name.value ;
```

like in

```
string MyElmWidth = htmlTextWriterStyle.width.ToString();
```

and could be assigned like a list so I could dynamically populate it via foreach loop

(not having to hard Code variables & values)

a collection or something rather a list like in this code:

```
                public static List<string> EnumToStrLst<T>()
                {
                    Array values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(T));
                    T[] result = (T[])values;
                    List<string> strlst = new List<string>();
                    foreach (var item in result)
                    {
                        string e = item.ToString();

                        strlst.Add(e);
                    }
                    return strlst;
                }
```

populating a `List<string>` is then done this way:

```
List<string> testLstStr = EnumToStrLst<htmlTextWriterStyle>()
```

though the Whole issue here is the access to it's values- a not so elegant way as in an enum:

```
testLstStr.elementAt(index)
```

opposed to

```
enumName.valueName
```

Comment: did you think about an Extension Method instead?

Comment: @AlexPeta not realy that experienced with Ext' Methods . i'll be happy to adapt any elegant approach that will result in a data that could be accessed as mentioned

Comment: was on the wrong path there , HtmlTextWriterStyle is an enum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only way i could do it without giving up the ease of access 
is with seald class and const strings 
copied it from enums meta data with summary(laid out nicely with only one type declaration)

```
namespace Style
{
    public sealed class StlProps
    {
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies the HTML backgroundcolor style.
    public const string BgColor = "BackgroundColor",
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies the HTML backgroundimage style.
    BackgroundImage = "BackgroundImage",
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies the HTML bordercollapse style.
    BorderCollapse = "BorderCollapse",
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies the HTML bordercolor style.
    BorderColor = "BorderColor",
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies the HTML borderstyle style.
    BorderStyle = "BorderStyle",
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies the HTML borderwidth style.
    BorderWidth = "BorderWidth",
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies the HTML color style.
    Color = "Color",
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies the HTML fontfamily style.
    FontFamily = "FontFamily",
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies the HTML fontsize style.
    FontSize = "FontSize",
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies the HTML fontstyle style.
    FontStyle = "FontStyle",
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies the HTML fontheight style.
    FontWeight = "FontWeight",
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies the HTML height style.
    Height = "Height",
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies the HTML textdecoration style.
    TextDecoration = "TextDecoration",
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies the HTML width style.
    Width = "Width",
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies the HTML liststyleimage style.
    ListStyleImage = "ListStyleImage",
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies the HTML liststyletype style.
    ListStyleType = "ListStyleType",
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies the HTML cursor style.
    Cursor = "Cursor",
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies the HTML direction style.
    Direction = "Direction",
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies the HTML display style.
    Display = "Display",
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies the HTML filter style.
    Filter = "Filter",
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies the HTML fontvariant style.
    FontVariant = "FontVariant",
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies the HTML left style.
    Left = "Left",
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies the HTML margin style.
    Margin = "Margin",
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies the HTML marginbottom style.
    MarginBottom = "MarginBottom",
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies the HTML marginleft style.
    MarginLeft = "MarginLeft",
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies the HTML marginright style.
    MarginRight = "MarginRight",
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies the HTML margintop style.
    MarginTop = "MarginTop",
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies the HTML overflow style.
    Overflow = "Overflow",
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies the HTML overflowx style.
    OverflowX = "OverflowX",
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies the HTML overflowy style.
    OverflowY = "OverflowY",
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies the HTML padding style.
    Padding = "Padding",
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies the HTML paddingbottom style.
    PaddingBottom = "PaddingBottom",
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies the HTML paddingleft style.
    PaddingLeft = "PaddingLeft",
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies the HTML paddingright style.
    PaddingRight = "PaddingRight",
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies the HTML paddingtop style.
    PaddingTop = "PaddingTop",
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies the HTML position style.
    Position = "Position",
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies the HTML textalign style.
    TextAlign = "TextAlign",
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies the HTML verticalalign style.
    VerticalAlign = "VerticalAlign",
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies the HTML textoverflow style.
    TextOverflow = "TextOverflow",
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies the HTML top style.
    Top = "Top",
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies the HTML visibility style.
    Visibility = "Visibility",
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies the HTML whitespace style.
    WhiteSpace = "WhiteSpace",
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies the HTML zindex style.
    ZIndex = "ZIndex";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this is not tested,but what about creating a wrapper class like this :

```
public class HtmlTextWrapper {

//private members
   private HtmlTextWriterStyle _htmlTextWriterStyle;


//public props same as the wrapped htmltextwriterstyle
    public string BackgroundColor { 
        get
        {
            if (_htmlTextWriterStyle != null)
            {
                return _htmlTextWriterStyle.BackgroundColor;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            if (_htmlTextWriterStyle != null)
            {
                this._htmlTextWriterStyle.BackgroundColor = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public string BackgroundImage {get;set; }
    //....
    //....


//construcor
     public HtmlTextWrapper(HtmlTextWriterStyle other)
     {
            _htmlTextWriterStyle = other;
     }



}
```

and this way, you could just work with this wrapper class

Comment: i could have done other things but your example includes a way that involves hardCoding the names & values not generating it dinamically as in List<string> (at least populating is done programmatically) though not accessing it's values/data

Comment: though closest way i Could think of is `Dictionary<string, string>`

Comment: Dictionary won't do ither, i guess i'll just have to make it my self the hard(coded) way via const string inside a Seald Class.